# Simple update class instance

Tags: python, class

I would like to create a very simple class in Python such that, starting from an initial list of elements [3,7,2,7,81], an other list of numbers can be added, in this case a single element 40. Here is my solution:

```
class Add_elements:

    def add(self, elements):
        list = [self.list,elements]
        return list

add_elements = Add_elements()
add_elements.add([3,7,2,7,81])
add_elements.add([40])
```

This should return something like:

> [[3,7,2,7,81],40]

The issue with this is that the list of elements is reset every time, there is no memory of the previous elements added. Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want a class and not a function?

Comment: Can you ensure that the code you've posted mirrors what you're working on locally? This might not function the way you expect, as you haven't indented the two lines in your `def add`  block correctly.

Comment: The `list` instance property should be defined in the constructor (the `__init__` function). I get `AttributeError: 'Add_elements' object has no attribute 'list'` when calling your function

Comment: You need to set `self.list` in the `__init__` function. e.g. `def __init__(): self.list = []` and then change `list` to `self.list` in both places in your `add` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need an initialiser to initialise `self.list`:

```
class Add_elements:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = None

    def add(self, elements):
        if self.list is None:
            self.list = elements
        else:
            self.list = [self.list,elements]
        return self.list
```

This will make `list` an attribute of `Add_elements` - part of its state. And when you call `add`, it changes that state.

EDIT:

If you want to remove the square brackets when calling `add`, you can do something like this:

```
def add(self, *elements):
    if self.list is None:
        self.list = list(elements)
    else:
        self.list = [self.list,list(elements)]
    return self.list
```

Comment: Hi, this one works. Do you know any elegant way to remove all the round or square brackets each time add() is called?

Comment: I added my solution for the square brackets.